# How could this pandas code work (lambda)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

[image]

- The red highlight part is pd.read_csv, we can get a dataframe type object here;
- Then the blue highlight part is a list with lambda function (we can filter account ID when reading the CSV file).

This method seems very smart, but a bit confusing to me. Could anyone explain how this could work as a filter? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does that code actually work? I wouldn't think subscripting on a function should work, unless pandas is expecting that as a possibility.

Comment: Sure enough, just tested it, and pandas does accept a function in the square brackets, and applies that function to every row, keeping the row if the function returns a truthy value!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[...]` part is called indexing, and basically there you're just creating a function (a "lambda" function) and indexing the dataframe with it. What you're going to get out of it is all the rows where `acct_id` is `OVIWFZA`.

It's identical to this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/client.csv', nrows=5)
df = df[df['acct_id'] == 'OVIWFZA']
```